# Eclipse RCP Product Export failed when I check option Generate P2 Repository

Tags: eclipse, product, rcp, pde, p2

I have a feature-based RCP Product.
When I export the product checking option Generate P2 Repository, it is not exported right.
It generates logs zip file but it does not have any error information.
It just has some information about warning and info.

I can export the product right when I don't check option Generate P2 Repository.

I am using eclipse 2020-06 and jdk11.
And I have start level configuration like the below.

```
       <configurations>
      <plugin id="org.apache.felix.scr" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.ds" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
   </configurations>
```

And .log in workspace .metadata says like the below.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.pde.core 2 0 2022-04-29 15:17:04.122
!MESSAGE Compilation errors occurred during the operation.  A zip file containing the build logs has been generated and placed at C:\Users\Administrator\workspace-2022-P6\tesw
```

Hope anyone could help me with this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Export RCP is no longer supported, [tag:tycho] is the correct way to build RCPs. Tutorial [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html)

Comment: @greg-449 but I can export the product without checking the option "Generate P2 Repository" , and the product just works fine. Do they not support exporting a product with P2 Repository?  I happened to need to support update sites for my tool. That's why I am trying to export it with p2 repository.

Comment: Bits of the old export may work but bugs are not being fixed. Tycho supports producing a repository. Sorry, but you are not likely to get any answers about the old export method.

Comment: Ok. but do you know how to see the logs other than those in logs.zip? There is no error in logs.zip that is generated during exporting the product. Is there anything like some arguments to generate logs? It only says like the below. 
Compilation errors occurred during the operation.  A zip file containing the build logs has been generated and placed at....

Comment: As I already said Export RCP is no longer supported, you have probably hit one of the unfixed bugs. I remember having to switch to Tycho because of something like this, but I no longer remember any details.